# Flex: Update a label's text, which is a variable

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a label that get it's value from a var when you click on a button. The var has already been declared:

```
public function clickevent
{
label.text = aVariable; 
}
```

Now I know that if i have a label like this:

```
<s:Label id="label2" text="{aVariable}"/>
```

and aVariable is empty, label2's text is Null (it doesn't give an error, just "Null" in my situation). This is my current situation.

What I'd like to know is when I later on change the aVariable's value to a string "hasChanged", for example. The label2's text should also change to "hasChanged" without the user having to push a button or anything to make this change. How can this be done?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306896/as3-can-i-detect-change-of-value-of-a-variable-using-addeventlistener

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question but if your variable is declared as "bindable", no matter if your script change its value or a button, your text propertie of the label will follow as it is binded.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            private var aVariable:String;

            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                aVariable = "My new value";
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>

    <s:Label text="{aVariable}"/>

    <s:Button label="Click me" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: Okay, it worked. Funny that i often bind vars for other reasons, but i didn't know it also fixes this problem. however i have the same problem on another var, but a bit more complicated. i'll add my 2nd part of the question soon. –

Comment: I posted the more advanced question here (to keep things organised): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423226/update-a-var-which-gets-it-its-value-from-another-component

Answer (score 3):

It may also be of note that declaring any variable in the declarations block makes it Bindable by default:

```
<fx:Declarations>
  <fx:String id="aVariable" />
</fx:Declarations>

<s:Label text="{aVariable}" />

<s:Button label="Click Me" click="aVariable='Clicked!'" />
```

This is just an alternative to the declaration in the Script block.

Comment: I posted the more advanced question here (to keep things organised): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423226/update-a-var-which-gets-it-its-value-from-another-component

Answer (score 2):

Declare your variable with the [Bindable] tag, like:

```
[Bindable] private var aVariable:String;
```

Now, whenever the value of the variable aVariable is changed, it is reflected on the label.

Comment: Okay, it worked. Funny that i often bind vars vor other reasons, but i didn't know it also fixes this problem. however i have the same problem on another var, but a bit more complicated. i'll add my 2nd part of the question soon.

Comment: I posted the more advanced question here (to keep things organised): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423226/update-a-var-which-gets-it-its-value-from-another-component