# Update a var, which get's it it's value from another component

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm having trouble with updating a var and firing a function with it on creationcomplete.

In the main component i declared a var artist. This var certainly works and has a value. I also need that var in another component: a profile component. I am able to get that var with:

```
newVar = Maincomp(this.parentApplication).artist;
```

I use the newVar in an API in the profile component. When i launch the API function with a mouseEvent, it works. However, i want to launch the API function on creationComplete and than the var doesn't work: it returns Null. I hoped that making all the involved vars bindable would help, but it doesn't. How can this be fixed?

Extra code to make my case clearer:

In main comp:

```
        public function handleclick(cName:String):void
        {
            vName = "aVariableIGetFromAnAPI";
        }
```

in profile comp:

```
                    public function zoekImages(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            var api_URL:String = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/';
            var api_imagemethod:String = 'artist.getImages';
            var api_key:String = '99f1f497c0bd598f1ec20571a38e2219';
            artistImage = DifficultierAPI(this.parentApplication).vName;
            var autocorrect:String = '1';
            var limit:String = '4'; 
            api_imagerequest = api_URL + '?method=' + api_imagemethod  + '&artist=' + artistImage + '&autocorrect=' + autocorrect + '&api_key=' + api_key + '&limit=' + limit;
            imageRequest.send(); // hier maak je connectie met lastfm
        }
```

This code works, but point is that this code works if i call it with a MouseEvent, but doesn't when it needs to launch on creationcomplete. Or well, it returns Null instead of a value. I thought that making the involved vars bindable would fix it, but it doesn't. Any help?

Comment: I extended the code in the example. i hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to bind the variable all along from the main application to the nested component, simply declare a variable as public and bindable within your component :

**Main application**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" xmlns:Components="Components.*">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            public var myMainVar:String;

            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                myMainVar = "Hi there!";
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>

    <s:Button label="Click me to update the coponent's variable" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>

    <Components:MyCustomComponent myComponentVar="{myMainVar}"/>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

**Nested component**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            public var myComponentVar:String;
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Label text="{myComponentVar}"/>

</s:Group>
```

I hope it is what you're looking for :-)

Comment: i'll try this as soon as possible. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this, but the same problem occurs: I only get Null, not an updated value of the var.

Comment: The creationComplete event is coming from the main app or from the nested component?

Comment: Also, try to use the applicationComplete event instead of creationComplete. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ee6.html

Comment: Okay. Actually, if i just call the the var in a label's text, it shows. But i need the var in the function "zoekprofile", but then it returns Null, so it only works outside a function now. i'll try the applicationcomplete instead of creationcomplete.

Comment: Don't forget to make all your variables public and bindable, in your app and in your component. I can't see the variable definition of "newVar = Maincomp(this.parentApplication).artist;", it may be the problem..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5695/discussion-between-kevin-verhoeven-and-jivago)